# Custom Infowindow Image Height in CartoDB

Tags: carto, carto-js

I have a problem in CartoDB Where I want the Infowindow's embedded header image to have a minimum height to allow for off-the-shelf images from a journalist.

I've started with [this](https://gist.github.com/javisantana/6696187), which allows me to change the height of the CartoDB Info Window, but I am having trouble changing the image itself.

[This](http://brianbancroft.github.io/cartodb-image-height.html) is how it looks [using this code](https://gist.github.com/brianbancroft/9e27956e77482085d09d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up asking through the helpful CartoDB staff. The HTML elements within the infowindow popup can be edited for height, but the trick is getting the right one. Setting the min-height on the cartodb popup headed did the trick!